# angular-ui select2 breaks data-binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser, angular-ui, angularjs-select2

I have a service that stores my data as single source of truth, so my controllers can change the model by making calls to the service and other controllers will get synchronized model data.

```
angular.module('fmAppApp').factory('CategoryService', function(Category) {
  var catServiceInstance, categories;
  categories = Category.query(); // Category is ng-resource
  return catServiceInstance = {
      getCategories: function() {
         return categories;
      },
      addCategory: function(category) {
         categories.push(category)
      }
  };
});
```

It was working perfectly both in chrome and firefox untill I integrated angular-ui select2 module to utilize its `ui-select` directive. I populate it with options like this:

```
 <ui-select-choices refresh="addNewObj($select.search)" refresh-delay="0" repeat="category in categories | filter: {name: $select.search}">
```

Now when I add category in one controller I don't see it appear in the dropdown list. Strangely, it is so only in firefox. In chrome it works fine. I'd like to hear some explanation and actions I need to take to make it work in both these browsers.

Comment: is there any extension or plugin running in firefox which restricts your functions

Comment: no, I mean it works in chrome, but breaks in firefox. and answering your question no, that I am aware of

Comment: yes,actually meant firefox

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?